# the usage of "most" as in "the place that you most like to visit"

Tags: word-usage

1. the place that you most like to visit
2. the place that you like to visit most
3. the place that you like to visit the most
4. the activity that you most want to do
5. the activity that you want to do most
6. the activity that you want to do the most
7. How can I better do it?
8. How can I do it better?

I am a little surprised to hear sentence 1,4,7 (better/most before verbs), as if it's the preferred way. While I can accept this usage, I wonder which sentences above are more standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the adverb "most" is acting as a modifier of the verb "like" or "want", then it is natural to place it in front of the verb.

However, adverb placement is influenced a lot by idiom and special cases. It's more common to place "better" at the end: "How can I do it better".